# Exception in Flying Saucer when processing images for custom UserAgentCallback

Tags: image, pdf, flying-saucer

I've setup a test environment for Flying Saucer R8, and is testing building PDF's from templates and data. I'm using a custom UserAgentCallback to read external js/css and images locally from filesystem. The problem occured when introducing the following custom UserAgentCallback:

```
package support;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent;

public class FileUserAgent extends NaiveUserAgent {
    @Override
    public String resolveURI(String uri) {
        URL url = null;
        String path = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(uri);
            path = url.getPath();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // only path present
            path = uri;
        }
        if (path.charAt(0) == '/') {
            path = path.substring(1, path.length());
        }
        return path;
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream resolveAndOpenStream(String filepath) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(filepath);
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("an error occured when reading resource: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return is;
    }
}
```

The UserAgentCallback is able to read CSS without any problem, but when reading images either from src or background-image property i get the followng exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.AWTFSImage$OldAWTFSImage cannot be cast to org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFSImage
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextOutputDevice.drawImage(ITextOutputDevice.java:761)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.AbstractOutputDevice.paintTiles(AbstractOutputDevice.java:300)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.AbstractOutputDevice.paintBackground0(AbstractOutputDevice.java:245)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.AbstractOutputDevice.paintBackground(AbstractOutputDevice.java:191)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextOutputDevice.paintBackground(ITextOutputDevice.java:187)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.Box.paintBackground(Box.java:436)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.Layer.paintBackgroundsAndBorders(Layer.java:243)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.Layer.paint(Layer.java:329)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.paintPage(ITextRenderer.java:384)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.writePDF(ITextRenderer.java:348)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:315)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:246)
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i read in the flying-saucer forum you have to make sure to return the right ImageResource!

what helped for me was extending the class with ITextUserAgent instead of NaiveUserAgent. (ITextUserAgent extends NaiveUserAgent).